# "Предоставьте выбор нам" в мобильной версии

Tags: дефект, дизайн, знаки, мобильная-версия

При получении очередного знака в профиле участника (мобильная версия) появляется баннер с поздравлением и кнопка <kbd>Доверьте выбор нам</kbd> для наблюдения за прогрессом по следующему знаку:

> [image: Поздравление]

При нажатии на упомянутую кнопку часть страницы обновляется, но с дефектами:

> [image: Следующий знак баг]

К видимым дефектам можно отнести следующие:

- Отсутствие отступов: как от левого края страницы, так и между элементами по вертикали.
- Двойные круги разного размера в блоках "Золото", "Серебро", "Бронза".
- Текстовое значение прогресса по следующему знаку, т.е. `382/600` отображается слева, а справа.

После ручного обновления страницы через <kbd>F5</kbd> она уже отображается корректно, но несколько иначе:

> [image: Следующий знак Ок]

---

After awarding the next badge, in the user profile page appears congratulation banner with a button <kbd>Let us pick</kbd>. When button is pressed the page is updated, but within some design bugs:

- There are no indents from the left edge of the page and between elements vertically.
- Double circles of different sizes in gold, silver and bronze blocks.
- Text value of the next badge (i.e. `382/600`) is placed on the left, but should be on the right side of the progress bar.

After manual refresh via <kbd>F5</kbd> page looks normally.

Comment: Пробный камень по оформлению дефекта в новом виде. Надо ещё решить как быть с картинками и заголовком. Нужно ли всё это дублировать.

Comment: Заодно проверим, насколько таком способ публикации дефектов ускоряет их исправление.